# Vite & React : "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined" upon build

Tags: reactjs, npm, build, vite

i am trying to build a project using **Vite & React**. When i run `npm run dev` everything is working fine. But when i try to build the project with `npm run build`, the build completes and i open the HTML file using 'Five Server' : Nothing shows up in the browser, and i get this error in the console :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at index-079d3293.js:156:35879
    at index-079d3293.js:1:23
    at index-079d3293.js:180:36233
```

I did some research and the error is because the js files that is build is used as a module in the index.html, and its using `require()` statements. And i don't know what to solve this error (i don't want to manually change require() manually in a generated file)

Here is the generated HTML file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Vite + React</title>
    <script type="module" crossorigin src="/assets/index-079d3293.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/index-45f2eabe.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the package.json

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint src --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@heroicons/react": "^2.0.17",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-chat-engine-advanced": "^0.1.28",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dropzone": "^14.2.3",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.11.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^18.16.3",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.28",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.38.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.3.4",
    "sass": "^1.62.1",
    "vite": "^4.3.2"
  }
}
```

And here is the vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import path from 'path'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  resolve: {
    alias: [{find: '@', replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')}]
  }
})
```

i tried getting rid of the `type="module"` but there were export statements in the generated javascript, so that didn't work.